# App icon duplicated with a 'grayish' overlay on iPhone 6 with iOS 8

Tags: ios, applications, bug, iphone

I've had this iPhone 6 for a week now. Today my WhatsApp duplicated itself with a 'grayish' overlay on it. I can move it around, but when tapping it nothing happens. How does this happen and how can I get rid of this?

I guess it might have happened after an update, it's the second time this has happened. First time it happened a different app duplicated itself just like this. I've been searching the Internet, but could not find any explanation/solution.  Here's a screenshot of it:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

This happens sometimes when an app installation or update fails and SpringBoard still shows the icon from cache.

To fix it, try any of the following:

- Sometimes, holding down on any icon to start edit mode, then tapping the **×** to delete the placeholder will work fine.
- Reboot—this clears SpringBoard cache.
- If your device is jailbroken, run `uicache` as mobile, then respring.

Comment: The '×' does not appear on this specific clone, i will edit the post while i make a reboot as you suggested. :)

Comment: Reboot worked fine, hopefully this bug will stop repeating itself and Apple will fix this issue soon. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Same thing happenend to me on my brand new iPhone 6. Reboot fixed the issue thanks for the tip

Comment: I had the same thing but the name under it kept changing. It said twitter when I saw it, then switched to target and then podcast. It did not have the x to delete and disappeared when I rebooted. It looks unlike any app I have